# Stop and wait protocol - what will happen when timer equals roundtrip time

Tags: network-protocols

I understand the stop-and-wait protocol but unsure how a certain scenario is handled.
What will happen when using the stop-and-wait protocol, the timer expires (timeout event occurs) exactly when the ack frame arrives. This situation is when the roundtrip time for a frame (with ACK) is the same as the timer.

I know its more hypothetical but it is a question that was asked of me. I am guessing it has something to do with what state the sender is in. ie blocking state or ready state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation problem.  Usually, and the simplest case, is that the protocol or the state machine processes one event at a time. If the timeout is processed before the ACK is processed, the message may be be re-sent. Then when the ACK is processed it can be considered as the ACK for the second message and the second ACK just a repeated one and dropped. At the other side, the other node needs to detect the second message is repeated and drop it or something else that doesn't change its state. This other node has to send an ACK for the second message received because it doesn't know if the previous ACK was not received.

Other possibility is that the ACK is processed before the timeout. For this, the timeout event needs to have data relating it to a sent message. Then when the timeout event is processed, the state machine detects the timeout corresponds to a message that was already ACK'ed.

For handling these special situations, you need to use additional data: messages and ACK need to have sequence numbers. Other data might be necessary for handling other situations.

You can see the implementation of such protocol robustness mechanisms in Tanenbaum's Computer Networks book, in chapter 3, Data Link Layer, and in TCP (not a stop&wait protocol) chapter.